# How to define DB SKU size in Azure SQL database

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I am learning Azure DB and new to it.
I am trying basic Handson on it.

Requirement is to create a DB with edition as Basic, size 100 MB, 5 DTU.

I tried following command in Azure CLI:

```
az sql db create -n $dbname --server $servername -g $RGname --edition Basic --capacity 5
```

It is giving SKU with size null. I tried to add `--max-size 100MB` to this command. But still it is showing size as null.

Can you please help with how to define size.

Answer (score 3):

The below will create a SQL database in Basic tier, 5 DTU and 100MB

```
az sql db create -g <your-resource-group> -s <your-database-server> -n <your-db-name> -e Basic --max-size 100MB
```

The command you have shared also works fine. I was able to create a DB and verify in Portal and size was 100MB.

Please note that Basic tier is by default 5 DTU and we need not explicitly specify.

Just wondering if you are referring to the output of the command in your CLI console where the SKU.size is mentioned as null

```
  "sku": {
    "capacity": 5,
    "family": null,
    "name": "Basic",
    "size": **null**,
    "tier": "Basic"
  },
```

Even though it returns as null, the DB gets created with the specified size.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE-**

I figured out that you will be able to see the size that you have specified in the CLI command (100MB in this case) in the "maxSizeByte" attribute of the JSON

```
.
.
. 
"managedBy": null,
  "maxLogSizeBytes": null,
  "maxSizeBytes": **104857600**,
  "minCapacity": null,
.
.
.
```

Comment: OP had already mentioned that `--max-size` attribute is not working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and help. It is visible in portal. But why is it not showing in SKU json in CLI.

Comment: @Gopesh it shows the size as "maxSizeBytes" (Updating the answer) if this answers your question, kindly accept the answer or upvote so that it will be easier for the community to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this

```
  az sql db create -g akshandsonlab -s <unique-sqlserver-name> -n mhcdb --service-objective Basic --max-size 100MB
```

Comment: OP had already mentioned that `--max-size` attribute is not working.